# Non-US citizen with warrant

Tags: visas, usa, canada, india, indonesia

If I have a bench warrant, will I able to leave the United States without any issues? Because my charge was PL 145.05 mischief, and I didn't attend court in New York, will I able to go to my home country from a different state's international airport?

Comment: Do you intend to go to or transit in Canada/India/Indonesia?

Comment: Flying from an airport in a different state isn't likely to change the outcome.  I don't think local authorities are notified of departing passengers, only CBP.  CBP will know about your warrant -- or not know about it -- regardless of which state you fly from.

Comment: Why not going to court? Worst case you will be deported, but so probably without a ban or a shorted ban, compared to flying away. -- but ask a lawyer

Comment: This is a classic "consult a lawyer" question.  The TSA or CBP may or may not know about your warrant, (either now or even any time in the future when you simply fly over the US).  If they know, you may or may not be arrested on the spot (depending on the warrant).  But the best outcome is to address the warrant.  Turn yourself in deal with the consequences.

Comment: @PeterM since CBP won't be present when they learn that OP is planning to leave the country, I don't think they can make an arrest "on the spot."  More likely they'd be waiting at the gate.

Comment: @phoog My comment was predicated on the warrant being issued and the authorities being knowledgeable about it's existence.  Once that state is reached you are liable to be arrested at any time you make contact with LEO.  Once they know they won't say "let's wait until he reaches the gate before arresting him".

Comment: You mean non us citizen can exits country if they have bench warrant I mean could be but I wanna no how exit works and why they can't able to arrest when you leaving country usa to another your home country with non us citizen have bench warrant??? I mean explain little more

Comment: @PeterM suppose someone checks in for a flight and the "outstanding warrant" alert goes off.  The nearest law enforcement officer is minutes away in an office somewhere.  The only place they're going to have a good chance of making contact with the subject of the warrant is going to be the gate.  TSA agents are not law enforcement officers.

Comment: @phoog Sure TSA do not have the power to arrest, but they do have the power to detain - and they can very quickly call people who do have the power to arrest